# Macro for inserting subsection using AucTeX?

Tags: sectioning, auctex, aquamacs

`C-c C-s` produces a <strike>dialog</strike> hook which says `Level: (default section)`. The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Sectioning.html) says that the code for subsection is supposed to be `3`. But if one types `3 RET`, after completing the remaining <strike>dialogs</strike> hooks for the section name and label, one gets

```
\3{title}
\label{label}
```

which obviously is not the expected or desired behavior.

> **Question:** Is there a way to fix this behavior so that it behaves more like I expected?

Writing out the entire word `subsection` would seem to nullify the entire point of AucTeX macros. Do people commonly need to modify AucTeX's defaults substantially, like is done [here](http://www.stefanom.org/setting-up-a-nice-auctex-environment-on-mac-os-x/)? Any suggestions for how to change this, get use to this, or try a different solution for inserting sections, subsections, etc. into a document altogether would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** [The manual says further that](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Sectioning.html):

```
User Option: LaTeX-section-hook
List of hooks to run when a new section is inserted.

The following variables are set before the hooks are run

level
Numeric section level, default set by prefix arg to LaTeX-section.

name
Name of the sectioning command, derived from level.
```

To me it seems like when the hook/dialog/prompt (I am new to emacs and do not know the correct terminology) asks for the `Level` which should be a numeric, and from which AucTeX should deduce `Name`, instead it is asking for `Name`. Is this correct, and perhaps my settings are interfering with AucTeX somehow? (I am using the version of AucTeX coming with an AquaMacs installation, which is presumably heavily pre-configured.)

**EDIT:** The manual online contradicts the information given about the LaTeX-section hooks inside of emacs, specifically that says that:

`LaTeX-section-heading
        Hook to prompt for LaTeX section name. Hide
    Insert this hook into ‘LaTeX-section-hook’ to allow the user to change
    the name of the sectioning command inserted with ‘M-x LaTeX-section’.`

In other words, this hook is intentionally designed to *only* allow the user to specify the name, *not* the level. This in direct contrast to the online AucTeX documentation which falsely claims that this hook allows one to change the name and the level.

Again, this does not make sense to me -- the level uniquely determines the name, does it not? So why allow the user to specify an incorrect section command, like `\notasection{}`, which also takes longer to type than the level number anyway, and additionally not allow the level of the section to specified? It makes no sense to me.

It also says that

`The following variables are set before the hooks are run: level, name, ...`

i.e. that it sets the value of the level before any of the hooks are run. *And* none of the hooks allow one to change the value of the level.

The documentation says something about the level being a prefix argument. As far as I can tell, this means that it can only be changed in an emacs lisp configuration file, but can not be changed in real time when using emacs, which does not make sense to me. This is based off of the emacs documentation for "Prefix Command Arguments" [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html), which I don't actually understand. So I guess this question comes down to how to specify a prefix command argument in real time while using emacs.

Comment: Probably better to ask on the auctex mailing list. Manuals are often the last thing developers think about. Looking in the code (I use 11.90), that numbered list is mentions for `LaTeX-section`, but I get the same as you. So ask the developers, https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/mailing-lists.html

Comment: @daleif I just figured it out -- see the answer below. The documentation is correct, it just doesn't make sense to a novice like me who doesn't understand what prefix arguments are or how to specify them.

Comment: I've always just used `C-c C-s subsec TAB`, easier to remember

Comment: @daleif If that works for you, then of course feel free to use it.

Comment: It just think that it is more natural, not many users remember these numbers

Comment: @daleif I agree that the numbers are probably not the best design choice. I just don't want to type in `subsu TAB` everytime I need a subsubsection when I remember (right now at least) that I can just do `C-u 4` before `C-c C-s`. Arguably all of the commands in emacs are just as arbitrary and have to be relegated to muscle memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, Emacs' user interface is somewhat Minibuffer-tabcompletion-centric.  If you don't like the current implementation of `LaTeX-section`, you can add the following lines to your init file:

```lisp
(defun My-LaTeX-section ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((LaTeX-section-hook '(LaTeX-section-title
                              LaTeX-section-section
                              LaTeX-section-label)))
    (LaTeX-section
     (read-number "Level: "))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c s") #'My-LaTeX-section))
          t)
```

It defines a new function `My-LaTeX-section` which locally rebinds the value of `LaTeX-section-hook` before it asks you only for a number which is passed to the original implementation of `LaTeX-section`.  Next, it maps the key binding <kbd>C-c s</kbd> to your function in LaTeX mode.

Now, you can type <kbd>C-c s 2 RET</kbd> and will go directly to the query for title and label of a `section`.

Comment: This is impressive, thank you! This will probably take me some time to process/analyze, but I will let you know if/when I have any follow-up questions.

Answer (score 2):

After `C-c C-s` type `su` and then `TAB`. Emacs will autocomplete as far as possible.

Comment: This doesn't help much though because that doesn't allow one to distinguish between subsection, subsubsection, and subparagraph. The AucTeX documentation says that the command is supposed to query for the level using a numeric _arg_, but the LaTeX-section-heading hook is the only one available which modifies level, but doesn't query the user for the level. (Which doesn't make sense, because the level uniquely determines the name of the command, and the level is much easier and quicker to type than the entire name of the command, e.g. especially in the case of subsubsection.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it: first type `C-u` and then the level (a number between 0 through 6, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Sectioning.html)) and then type `C-c C-s` and fill in the prompts as normal.

So (after disabling `LaTeX-section-heading` under the settings for `LaTeX-section-hook`; see below), if one types `C-u 2 C-c C-s RET title RET label` one gets:

```
\section{title}
\label{label}
```

and if one types `C-u 4 C-c C-s anothertitle RET anotherlabel` one gets:

```
\subsubsection{anothertitle}
\label{anotherlabel}
```

To me this is still annoying, because I would prefer to be able to do `C-c C-s 4 RET anothertitle RET anotherlabel` but this is unfortunately the way the `LaTeX-section` command is currently written. If you know how to change these files and write in emacs lisp, and are therefore able to rewrite this function, then you probably wouldn't have had the same question that I had. In any case, it (1) explains what the AUCTeX documentation was talking about, and (2) is a *lot* easier than typing `C-c C-s subsubsection RET anothertitle RET anotherlabel`, (3) doesn't require typing out the whole section level name, which is supposed to be the point of these macros.

Behind the scenes, `C-u` is a shortcut ('key binding') for the command `universal-argument` ([see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html)) which allows you to specify the value of the ['prefix argument'](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) for the following command, which in this case is [`LaTeX-section`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Sectioning.html), whose shortcut is `C-c C-s`. So `C-u 4 C-c C-s` runs the `LaTeX-section` command with the prefix argument `4`, and `C-u 2 C-c C-s` runs the `LaTeX-section` command with the prefix argument `2` (which is [explained here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Sectioning.html) in the AUCTeX documentation).

**Note:** You might want to change the value of `LaTeX-section-hook` first so that it doesn't prompt you for the 'name' (which is useless). Do this by first typing `C-h  v` (*not* `C-h C-v`), and then type `LaTeX-section-hook` into the prompt for the variable name which should have been created by typing `C-h v`. This should open up a window which allows you to "customize the value of this variable", do that, then uncheck the box for `LaTeX-section-heading`. Now `C-c C-s` won't give the dialog box which asks for "the level", but which actually only asks for the 'name' (it would help if the terminology were consistent within the AucTeX commands and documentation version themselves, but it isn't). This is good, because if that prompt were still there, you could type `C-c C-s` `notasection` `...` `...` and get as output `\notasection{...} \label{...}`which is totally useless.

`C-h` leads to general help prompts, so typing the value `v` after `C-h` leads to the prompt for help and information about emacs variables, which allows their values to be changed.

Comment: +1 Note also that (a) `C-u C-c C-s` takes you down one level (b) you can write the numeric argument via ESC: `ESC 3 C-c C-s` etc.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I'll have to try both of these out later -- thank you for this advice!